# "Method https has died unexpectedly! Sub-process https received signal 4" after adding any additional repositories - Ubuntu Desktop 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, https

I am having a problem when trying to add any additional repositories in my Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS running on a VM in ESXi 7. The installation is fresh.

I'm facing the below problem when I try to `sudo apt update`

```
...
Reading package lists... Done                        
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.
```

This happens whenever I try to add repositories. I was trying to add Docker and Sublime text repositories as below:

```
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

```
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

When I remove the contents of `sources.list.d`, `sudo apt update` works fine.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

**Edit**:

On a related note, I also can't clone any repo. I tried using `curl`, `wget` and `git clone`. All these commands, give me the error:

```
error: git-remote-https died of signal 4
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
sudo GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1 apt-get update
```

this works for me

according to this
https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/ItKoVDieSow

and you need to add ~/.bashrc with this

```
export  GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1
```

for long-term use

Comment: I've added `export  GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1` in both `/root/.bashrc` and `theuser/.bashrc` and even I've restared the vm. But the problem exists. It's ok when I login as root and do `apt` commands without `sudo` but with `sudo` it give the error again.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above solutions even the accepted answer did not work for long-term use.
You can use `sudo GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1 apt-get update` (sudo is necessary even if you are logged in as root) every time you want to update packages, but if you're going to make it permanent and system-wide, you must add `export GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1` to the `/etc/environment` file. After this change, you can update the apt with sudo or without sudo with every user.

Answer (score 1):

- Update VMware in ESXi from 7.0.0 to 7.0.3.
- Reboot the guest VM.

It solved the problem for me. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating the VM under Compatibility mode - ESXi 6.0 virtual machine.
I had to do this on another Ubuntu-based image.