# Ubuntu 22.04 returns Sub-process https received signal 4 with sudo

Tags: apt, 22.04

When I want to update my vm I got the error:

```
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.
```

I searched the net and with [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1425180/458321) answer when I run `sudo GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1 apt-get update` with non root user the issue is fixed. But when I add the line `export  GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1` to both `/root/.bashrc` and `myuser/.bashrc` and execute `source .bashrc` the problem is not fixed.

When I login as `root` user (ssh `myuser@host` then `whoami` results `myuser`. then `sudo -i` and executing `whoami` results `root` in my VM.) and run the command without `sudo` it's ok. But even with the `root` user and the `sudo` prefix, the problem exists.

Comment: By default there is no root user in Ubuntu. So how are you logging in as root?

Comment: @David `ssh helmi@host` then `whoami` results `helmi`. then `sudo -i` and executing `whoami` results `root` in my VM.

Comment: That info needs to be in the question. Please use edit and add it. Others trying to help will have same concern.

Comment: @David is it now ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sudo GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1 apt-get update` every time you want to update packages, but if you're going to make it permanent and system-wide, you must add `export GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1` to the `/etc/environment` file.